# Confused about X Window and GNOME/KDE

Tags: linux, centos, vps

HI!

I am trying to set up FreeNX (one Remote X desktop software) on my VPS (CentOS 5.5). I have googled and found several different tutorials.

[One tutorial](http://www.hostloc.com/viewthread.php?tid=10071) says:

```
yum  groupinstall “X Window System”
yum groupinstall “GNOME Desktop Environment”
```

[Another](http://forums.spry.com/howtos/1485-remote-x-desktop-centos-freenx.html) says:

```
For a KDE desktop, do "yum install -y kdebase". 
For Gnome, do "yum install -y gnome-session".
```

I want to know:

1. **Is “X Window System” optional?** When I googled, it says “X Window System” is the backbone of KDE and GNOME. Some tutorials say “X Window System” eats lots of computer memory and it is optional if you have small computer memory. I am confused.
2. If I am going to install **Firefox and extensions** on my VPS, **is `yum install -y kdebase` enough?** Should I use `yum -y groupinstall "KDE (K Desktop Environment)"`?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 6):

Both KDE and GNOME run on top of X Windows. KDE and GNOME are [desktop environments](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desktop_environment) whereas [X Windows](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System) is the [windowing manager](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_window_manager).

Comment: But you still havent answered my question. Is `yum  groupinstall “X Window System”` optional here? Why do some tutorials say it is optional? Thx!

Comment: If you want a graphical desktop environment, then you need to install X Window system and then install GNOME or KDE.

Comment: Many years have passed, but to answer your specific question; yes, installing “GNOME Desktop Environment” will automatically install the “X Window System”, that's why some of the pages would say 'yum groupinstall “X Window System”' is optional.